# Laravel error after composer update. "In RouteCollection.php line 67: Array to string conversion"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel project cloned from my repository. However, after composer update this error pops out `"In RouteCollection.php line 67:Array to string conversion"`.

I have deleted the vendor folder and tried to do `composer dump-autoload then composer update` again but no luck.

below is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.10.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.4.1",
    "davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-laravel5",
    "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "kim/activity": "^1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/passport": "~3.0.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "~1.0",
    "nicolaslopezj/searchable": "1.*",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~2",
    "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.2.3",
    "willvincent/laravel-rateable": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
```

After composer update:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using . 
it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should 
avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize

In RouteCollection.php line 67:

Array to string conversion  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event 
returned with error code 1
```

After php artisan:

```
php artisan

In RouteCollection.php line 67:

Array to string conversion
```

Comment: Is .env correct ?

Comment: can you show us laravel.log output

Comment: i can see the .env.example but the main one is missing

Comment: how about laravel.log file

Comment: laravel.log`#51 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/topwyc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#52 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/topwyc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(114): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#53 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/topwyc/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#54 {main}`

Comment: We could not reproduce the issue. Can you clear the laravel.log, then run `composer update` so that we get fresh error log message and paste them to https://pastebin.com/ then you share https://pastebin.com/ link

Comment: I believe that the issue come from my .env file. The .env file is missing and i copied the file from my previous project then tried to do composer update again and it worked. Thank you @Cholowao for giving an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue occurred after deleting caches.

After executing the following command it was fixed.

```
rm -f bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Comment: This works for me also after running "php artisan optimize" and get the mentioned error.